GstMeta inherited class can't initiated properly - takes at most 0 arguments (TypeError)
The following line from the below code producs an error:
meta = GstExampleMeta(buffer)
The whole code:
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject

class GstExampleMeta(Gst.Meta):
    __gtype_name__ = 'GstExampleMeta'

    def __init__(self, buffer):
        super(GstExampleMeta, self).__init__()
        self.buffer = buffer        

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)

buffer = "example_buffer"
meta = GstExampleMeta(buffer)

The error:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
function takes at most 0 arguments (1 given)
File "/metadata.py", line 16, in 
meta = GstExampleMeta(buffer)
TypeError: function takes at most 0 arguments (1 given)
Why is that?
The buffer argument is meant for the GstExampleMeta class initiation, and then we're using super.init...
I tried a simplified version and its working properly:
# Parent class
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def display_info(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.name}, Age: {self.age}")

# Child class inheriting from Person
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, emp_id):
        # Call the parent class constructor with super()
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.emp_id = emp_id
    
    def display_info(self):
        super().display_info()  # Call parent's display_info method
        print(f"Employee ID: {self.emp_id}")

# Creating instances
person1 = Person("Alice", 30)
employee1 = Employee("Bob", 25, "E12345")

# Accessing methods
person1.display_info()  # Output: Name: Alice, Age: 30
employee1.display_info()  # Output: Name: Bob, Age: 25
                          #         Employee ID: E12345


